# display iframe youtube with a store link in phpmysql

Tags: php, mysql, iframe, youtube

I wonder why my code didn't display the iframe. I think its an src problem:

```
    $requete = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM envoie ORDER BY id');
    $requete->execute();
    $envoies = $requete->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($envoies as $envoie) :
  ?>
        <h3 class="comm"><?php echo $envoie['upload_title']; ?></h3>
        <h3 class="comm"><?php echo $envoie['upload_description']; ?></h3>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php $envoie['upload_lien'] ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <h3 class="comm"><?php echo $envoie['upload_temps']; ?></h3>
        <br><HR><br>
  
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: your not echoing the value

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I dont know how to answer your commentary but thanks for the answer it now works !